# Google Reader API feed number of items

Tags: google-reader

I have a folder in my Google Reader account called Test, with 200 items in. I only want to collect 20 items at a time.

According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI) I can add ?n=20 or ?count=20 to the url to get the first 20 items. But when I use this link http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/label/Test?count=20 or http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/label/Test?n=20 I get all 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/user/-/label/Test?ot=[epoch time]&r=a&xt=user/-/state/com.google/read&n=20&ck=[epoch time]&client=web

ot= is the time of the oldest article you want. time-(day*86400)
r= sort order a=magic n=desc o=asc
xt= what to exclude, the above excludes read articles, blank returns everything.
n= the number of articles to return
ck= not really sure, I put in the current epoch time and it works
client= string to identify client used.